# System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'add'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the below code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] Column)
    {
      List<string> selectionStrings;
      var colDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
            {"CATEGORY", "STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR"},
            {"SESSION_NUMBER", "STRS_SESSION3.SESSION_NUM"},
            {"SESSION_START_DATE","Trunc(STRS_SESSION3.START_DATE)"}
            };
      foreach (string col in Column)
      {
        string selector = colDict[col];
        selectionStrings.add(string.Format("{0} AS {1}", selector, col));
      }
      var strQuery = string.Format(@"SELECT {0}
                                     from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY");
  }
```

But getting the error in

```
selectionStrings.add(string.Format("{0} AS {1}", selector, col));
```

saying

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a
>   definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried adding `using System.Collections.Generic.List` but it doesn't work

Comment: Use `Add` instead. Note casing.

Comment: Do you mean `Add` with the uppercase A?

Comment: in addition to Shachaf.Gortler's answer: please also check whether you included: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I tried putting Add it now says in the selectionStrings error as "Use of unassigned local variable 'selectionStrings'

Comment: You have to initialise your list `List<string> selectionStrings;` => `List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `Add` instead of `add`,

```
selectionStrings.Add(string.Format("{0} AS {1}", selector, col));
```

also initialize selectionStrings , currently your code will throw an exception

```
List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't see anywhere you have initialized the list saying

```
List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
```

Also it's `Add()` and not `add`. VS Intellisense should helped in that case. are you using `Notepad` for writing code?

Answer (score 0):

Adding what Shachaf said, you also need to instantiate the List

```
    List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
```